# Expo React-Native IOS simulator not working due to version incompatibility

Tags: expo

i have downloaded a react native project which uses 40.0.0 version of expo go, however my IOS simulator supports the newer version of expo go versions like 41.0.0,42.0.0,43.0.0. how can i deal with this? is it by updating the version of the project ??[image: Please find the attached screen of simulator]

Answer (score 1):

that's happening because every few versions that Expo is updated, they deprecate the oldest one.

To fix this is very easy.

1 - Kill the server

2 - run `expo upgrade sdk version`

3 - run `expo start` again.

I hope it was helpful. :)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Your problem is that your project `expo SDK version` is too old (which is not recommended for several reasons, one of which is that you won't be able to upload your project to the stores later).

It is recommended to always have the Expo SDK of your project updated.